# Windows 8 doesn't recognize dual headphone/microphone jack

Tags: windows-8, audio, microphone

So I'm dual booting Windows 8.1 on a late 2014 Retina iMac, and I'm trying to move my mic input from the inbuilt mic to a headphone-mounted mic to reduce background noise. I've got a pair of Bose QuietComfort 15s which have a mic mounted on the headphone cable, and I've used both the headphone and microphone successfully on the Mac side. However, when I'm running in Windows, the sound device manager doesn't recognize that there is both a headphone and microphone plugged in; there's only the internal microphone in the recording tab, and I've tried showing disabled inputs with no luck.

How do I get Windows to recognize that I've plugged in a dual headphone/microphone?

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the type of drivers you have installed. The design of the headphone jack usually inform the port about the capabilities of the headphone.

You should check your Windows drivers that they are up to date and also support line in.

Here is an article from Wikipedia about this very issue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#Recording_equipment